# Mouse scrolling Event

Tags: c#, scroll, mouse

After browsing, I have found that

```
       mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL, 0, 0, 120, 0);
```

is used to simulate scrolling Event of the mouse where MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL=0x800.
But its not working with me. So please give me some other solutions to the problem.
I am working in C#.
Cheers

Comment: "It is not working" is not much use to us. Describe what you did and how it failed.

Comment: Just the mouse wheel is appearing at the co-ordinates i specify. I want the screen to scroll.May i know how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code works perfectly well. I trust you realise that you must have the input focus set to the control that you want to receive the mouse wheel input messages. Are you sure that you defined `MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL` correctly? The only other possibility that I can think of is that your window is already scrolled to the top. Note that your delta value of 120 will scroll upwards. Try passing `(uint)-120` instead which is what you would need to scroll down.

Comment: Ya you are right. My focus was on the form itself. Now its working. Thankyou:)

Comment: Could you please explain the arguments in the mouse_event ? 

I can't understand why the second and third is 0.

Whether I need to give that in the loop or it will do it for me ?

Comment: @Prabu Please ask a question. And you should use SendInput anyway. And faking input is probably the wrong solution to your problem.